# How to Create global session for SSO in Node js

Tags: node.js, angular, vue.js, google-chrome

I am trying to make SSO in my application and I search a lot about SSO and in the end, what I conclude is to create a global session auth them and then create a local session. I know how to create a local session but I don't know how to create a global session.

My one application is on vue and another is on angular. A domain like for vue abc.com/vue and abc.com/angular.

So what I want if the user login in any one of them then in another application user automatic authenticate that's was SSO means.

My problem how can I create a global session for both applications.

I used Express as my authentication server (Single Authentication Server).

Please Sorry if I write something weird.

In a simple word, I want SSO in my application

Comment: Well, `abc.com/vue` and `abc.com/angular` from the same browser can share the same server-side user session just fine as long as you don't manually restrict the session cookie to a path .  Anything you put in that session should be available to both.

Comment: What is both are open in two different systems? Different Browser.

Comment: Well, to implement SSO the second client must have access to some credential that proves they are the user that was previously logged in.  Within the same browser, you have the session cookie which can uniquely connect them to an express session object where you can have SSO info.  Without using the same browser, you'd have to invent or use some secure way to share a credential that proves who they are.  Otherwise, you need them to login from the new environment to prove who they are.

Comment: FYI, if you search for "nodejs single sign on", there are a lot of articles on the topic.  This is a widely discussed topic with various supporting modules available depending upon what exactly you're trying to do.